# How to get the current version of Chrome from an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a user-agent switcher for Chrome using the experimental API WebRequest, and I'd like to display the current user-agent used.

For that, I have to get the current version of Chrome, but I don't find anything about that in the doc and I can't access to the "chrome://version" page due to security considerations.

Do you have an idea to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
window.navigator.userAgent
```

on your backgroundpage?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the good old `navigator` object (`navigator.userAgent` is the exact property, but it contains many other informations), it's available to extensions.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function getChromeVersion(){
  var match = window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(?:e|ium)\/([0-9\.]+)/);
  return match ? match[1] : null;
}
```

or use https://github.com/DamonOehlman/detect-browser for Multi-Browser Support.