# Light & Dark browserAction icons in Chrome 51

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Chrome 51, incognito windows now have a dark toolbar background, while previous versions used a light background.  It's generally infeasible for a single 16x16 image to provide good contrast in both situations:

[image: IPvFoo with Light and Dark toolbars]

When displaying information to the user through a `browserAction` icon, by what mechanism can an extension provide dark-themed and light-themed icons, and switch between them depending on the current toolbar color?

[Link to source code for the pictured extension](https://github.com/pmarks-net/ipvfoo)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such simple mechanism (yet), and it sounds like an [excellent feature request to make](https://crbug.com/new) at the very least for the manifest.

It's possible to approximate this though, by detecting incognito tabs being open and replacing the browser action icon for *that tab only*.

```
var incognitoIcons = {
  19: "incognito19.png",
  38: "incognito38.png"
};

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
  if (tab.incognito) {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
      path: incognitoIcons,
      tabId: tab.id
    });
  }
});
```

If you're using a `"split"` [incognito behavior](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito) (non-default), you can simply detect that and change the global icon for the incognito instance:

```
// Somewhere in background during initialization
if (chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext) {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: incognitoIcons});
}
```

Note that content scripts can always rely on `inIncognitoContext`, so if you trigger a browser action icon change from them you can pass that along.

Obviously, you can do that with `imageData` instead of `path`, as is your case.

You may want to check the Chrome version while you're at it; I'm not aware of a better way than mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275200/how-to-get-the-current-version-of-chrome-from-an-extension).